# Json_Encode does not work while passing data between php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Here is the simple code in which I tried to pass a variable from php to js. When I don't use the quotes, I get an error, and when I do use them, the whole text gets passed to js.
What should I do, are there any other methods how?

```
<?php
  $linkid = 20;
?>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var count = "<?php echo json_encode($linkid); ?>";
    alert(count);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thats not how to `json_encode` in php.

Comment: You don't need json_encode for a primitive anyway. Try simply doing `var count = <?php echo $linkid; ?>;`. No quotes needed either for a number

Comment: I've tried it that way, and it still doesn't work. Is it a problem with the editor maybe? I'm using Atom

Comment: I just tried your code as it is, seems to be working fine with the quotes. [See here](https://repl.it/repls/TrivialUnhappyActivecontent#index.php).